# Parse Error while using Less CSS returns Unrecognised input error message with background properties?

Tags: css, less

I can't figure out what's wrong with my css using the LESS CSS library.

I'm getting this error when I run my site using LESS. But to me the CSS seems valid. What is wrong with my CSS and or can I not use LESS?

```
background: url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-clip: ( transparent, transparent ), url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( transparent, transparent ), url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( transparent, transparent ), url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background: -o-linear-gradient( transparent, transparent ) , url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% cover;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be having an invalid value for the `background-clip` property and it is causing less compiler to throw an error.

`background-clip` supports only `border-box` or `content-box` or `padding-box` or `inherit` as values.

For example, the below code compiles fine.

```
.sample{
    background: url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-clip: content-box;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient( transparent, transparent ), url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background: -moz-linear-gradient( transparent, transparent ), url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background: -o-linear-gradient( transparent, transparent ) , url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% cover;
}
```

[background-clip - MDN Specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-clip)

**Additional Note:**

The error is actually thrown because of a missing value indicated in the area below:

```
background-clip: ( transparent, transparent ), url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
/*--------------^*/
```

The below would compile fine but wouldn't have any effect because the value is not supported by `background-clip` property as per specifications.

```
background-clip: linear-gradient( transparent, transparent ), url(css/img/home-bg3.jpg) no-repeat;
```

Comment: Thanks! I totally over looked that. I've been starring at my CSS for far too long. Now I just gotta figure out how to circumvent gecko's missing clip features.